# Can i force mysql to perform subquery first?

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I have query like this:

```
SELECT `table_1`.* from `table_1`
  INNER JOIN `table_2` [...]
  INNER JOIN `table_3` [...]
WHERE `table_1`.`id` IN(
  SELECT `id` FROM [...]
)
AND [more conditions]
```

When I use EXPLAIN, there is 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY' at the end, but I want this subquery to be performed first, before other conditions.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT  `table_1`.*
FROM    `table_1`
INNER JOIN
        `table_2` [...]
INNER JOIN
        `table_3` [...]
WHERE   `table_1`.`id` IN
        (
        SELECT  `id`
        FROM    [...]
        )
        AND [more conditions]
```

If the inner table is properly indexed, the subquery here is not being "performed" at all in a strict sense of word.

Since the subquery is a part of an `IN` expression, the condition is pushed into the subquery and it's transformed into an `EXISTS`.

In fact, this subquery is evaluated on each step:

```
EXISTS
(
SELECT  NULL
FROM    [...]
WHERE   id = table1.id
)
```

You can actually see it in the detailed description provided by `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`.

That's why it's called `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`: the result of each evaluation depends on the value of `table1.id`. The subquery as such is not correlated, it's the optimized version that is correlated.

`MySQL` always evaluates the `EXISTS` clause after the more simple filters (since they are much easier to evaluate and there is a probability that the subquery won't be evaluated at all).

If you want the subquery to be evaluated all at once, rewrite the query as this:

```
SELECT  table_1.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT id
        FROM    [...]
        ) q
JOIN    table_1
ON      table_1.id = q.id
JOIN    table_2
ON      [...]
JOIN    table_3
ON      [...]
WHERE   [more conditions]
```

This forces the subquery to be leading in the join, which is more efficient if the subquery is small compared to `table_1`, and less efficient if the subquery is large compared to `table_1`.

If there is an index on `[...].id` used in the subquery, the subquery will be performed using an `INDEX FOR GROUP-BY`.

Comment: Problem with pushing the subquery down is that this is not possible if the subquery depends on a constant part of the outer query (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859809/how-to-optimize-dependent-subquery-with-constant-expression)

Answer (score 6):

this is a known bug in mysql: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25926

a useful workaround is to push down the subquery into another `select * from (subquery) as dt` type subquery.

Comment: The bug you mention affects only the `GROUP BY / DISTINCT` subqueries. An `IN` predicate over a subquery with a `DISTINCT` clause in it is equivalent to a `JOIN`.

Comment: no, the problem also occurs in queries that do not involve `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`. disproving this is simple: push the subquery down another level as i suggest and see if the DEPENDANT SUBQUERY changes to a DERIVED table. (and how do you know this query doesn't have  GROUP BY? the original poster did not provide the actual query.)

Comment: That workaround worked for me: it took a query that look 32 minutes down to 0.452 seconds.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could select the subquery's result into a temporary table first and then join to it in the main query.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to put the WHERE conditions for table1 into a subquery in the FROM clause. 
EG:

```
SELECT `table_1`.* 
FROM (
      SELECT * FROM `table_1` WHERE `table_1`.`id` IN (...)
     )
  INNER JOIN `table_2` [...]
  INNER JOIN `table_3` [...]
WHERE [more conditions]
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, no, you cannot.  Subqueries are actually run once for each row in the outer query.

I'd actually suggest that you convert this to another join, using `table_1.id` as your key to the other table.