# How to optimize dependent subquery with constant expression?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query and plan:

```
SELECT data.*
FROM data 
WHERE channel_id = 1
AND timestamp >= IFNULL((
    SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(timestamp) / 1000, "%Y-%m-%d"), INTERVAL 1 day)) * 1000 
    FROM aggregate 
    WHERE type = '3' AND aggregate.channel_id = data.channel_id 
), 0) 
AND timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d")) * 1000 

id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
'1' 'PRIMARY'   'data'  NULL    'ref'   'data_unique    IDX_ADF3F36372F5A1AA'   'IDX_ADF3F36372F5A1AA'  '5' 'const' '860512'    '11.11' 'Using where'
'2' 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY'    'aggregate' NULL    'ref'   'aggregate_unique   IDX_B77949FF72F5A1AA'   'aggregate_unique'  '7' 'volkszaehler.data.channel_id   const'  '1473'  '100.00'    'Using index'
```

The `data` table has a couple of million rows, all tables are indexed:

```
data: `channel_id`, `timestamp`
aggregate: `type`, `channel_id`, `timestamp`
```

The query becomes fast when the `aggregate.channel_id = data.channel_id` is replaced with the actual value of the `channel_id` of the outer query. And the dependent subquery becomes a simple subquery.

However, I'd rather not do this to allow the query to operate on >1 channel_ids at a time.

Why doesn't MySQL (5.7 homebrew) recognize that this subquery really is *not* dependent (or is it?) and how could it be optimized?

I've already verified that removing the `IFNULL` function or pushing it inwards does not cure the problem. I was also not successful in pushing down the subquery another level as suggested in [Can i force mysql to perform subquery first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766702/can-i-force-mysql-to-perform-subquery-first) since the `data.channel_id` reference is no longer known then.

Comment: It is possible to skip the sub query and rewrite it with a `JOIN` statement? If it is, does it increase the performance of your query?

Comment: @progman I don't see how?